# A semisimple Lie algebra has finitely many representation of a given finite dimension.

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional, semisimple Lie algebra, with Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$. I want to show that $\mathfrak{g}$ has finitely many representations of dimension $n$, up to isomorphism, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I know that finite dimensional representations of $\mathfrak{g}$ are the direct sum of their weight spaces. But since $\mathfrak{h}$ is finite dimensional, also $\mathfrak{h}^*$ is, thus there are only finitely many ways we can decompose a representation $V$, of dimension $n$, as the sum of its weight spaces.

I think that two representations with same root space decomposition are isomorphic,
thus concluding the argument, but I'm not quite sure how to prove it.

Comment: "thus there are only finitely many ways ...": This argument is incomplete (at least). Any $\mathfrak h^*$ of dimension $\ge 2$ still contains infinitely many distinct weights $w$ s.t. already the one-dimensional irreps given by those weights are mutually non-isomorphic, so *in principle* there are infinitely many ways a non-trivial $V$ can be built up from weight spaces. It is a deeper part of the structure theory (alluded to in the answer) that the weights which actually occur A) sit in a "discrete"/"integer" lattice and B) are "bounded", so that there are only finitely many possibilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For finite-dimensional repns, we know there is a unique highest weight (and weight space). By irreducibility, this weight space generates the whole repn. In particular, there is a chain of lowering operators (actions by elements in the negative weight spaces) taking the highest weight vector to the lowest weight vector (which we know has the negative of the weight of the highest). Thus, the dimension of the whole is certainly at least the number of steps it takes to get from highest to lowest weight, which is something like $\sum_i |\lambda_i|$ where (in some normalization) the $\lambda_i$ are the coordinates of the highest weight $\lambda$. Since highest weights are "integral" and "dominant", there are only finitely many with $\sum_i |\lambda_i|$ below a given bound.

Comment: Hello @paul garrett  I am very new to Lie groups and representation theory and I really like this answer but can you please explain why $\lambda$ being integral and dominant implies there are only finitely many weights below the given bound?

Comment: @NickCastillo, in brief, there is a partial ordering on weights so that all weights of a given repn are "between" the highest weight and the lowest weight, _and_ are hit by the "lowering operators", which do strictly "lower" the weight, and there's a finite-dimensional space of them, etc. And, e.g., the lowest and highest weights have only finitely-many weights "between" them. We do need to be sure about multiplicities, which is why I thought to use lowering operators.

Comment: thank you so much